# django rest return the same in different url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I use httpie to test my api,when I text

```
localhost:8000/users/
```

it show the user list,then i text

```
localhost:8000/users/jack/
```

it still show the user list,not the user detail,it's something wrong with my code?

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^', include('rest_framework.urls',namespace='rest_framework')),
url(r'regist/', Regist.as_view()),
url(r'users/', UserList.as_view()),
url(r'users/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$', UserDetail.as_view()),
]
```

views.py

```
class UserDetail(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class= UserSeriallizer

    def get_queryset(self):
        username = self.kwargs['username']
        user=User.objects.filter(username=username)
        return user

class UserList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSeriallizer(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in your urls, you need to close `r'users/$`, because Django can't go further `users/` without `$`
And why you use `ListAPIView` for retrieving single object?
You need `RetrieveAPIView` or `RetrieveUpdateAPIView` if you want change the data. And change your view like so:

```
class UserDetail(RetrieveAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'username'
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

You don't need `get_queryset` at all

[About mixins](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview)

Comment: got it, but the error still exist , does my views.py has another problem?

Comment: You mean django raise some errors? If it, can you put it in question. Also I update my answer, try it again

Comment: not error actually, I just can't get the user detail,and I tried your code, still the same

Comment: @何志遠 Oh! I got it, you forget close your urls before detail url, I update my answer.

Comment: Thanks Baterson! It really useful